# Typescript function with generic to return one of two types depending on what the user wants

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want a method `transform` that transforms some data into one of two types `CreateLocalProductRequestData` or `UpdateLocalProductRequestData` depending on what the caller wants. Both types have the same structure but `UpdateLocalProductRequestData` just has one additional property `product_id`

I've been trying to accomplish this with generics so that when the method is called you use the generic to pass in the expected response type and it will return that type for you but I haven't been able to get it to work. Here's what I have:

```
export interface CreateLocalProductRequestData {
    brand_id?: string;
    category_id: string;
    delivery_service_ids?: string;
    description: string;
    exemption_of_identifier_code?: ExemptionOfIdentifierCode;
    images: LocalProductImage[];
    is_cod_open: boolean;
    outer_product_id?: string;
    package_dimension_unit?: string;
    package_height: number;
    package_length?: number;
    package_weight: string;
    package_width?: number;
    product_attributes?: ProductAttribute[];
    product_certifications?: Certification[];
    product_name: string;
    product_video?: Video;
    skus: RequestSku[];
    size_chart?: SizeChart;
    warranty_period?: string;
    warranty_policy?: string;
}

export interface UpdateLocalProductRequestData extends CreateLocalProductRequestData {
    product_id: string;
}

async transform<T extends CreateLocalProductRequestData | UpdateLocalProductRequestData>(): Promise<T> {
  const category = await this.getCategory();
  const brand = await this.getBrand(category.id);
  
  const data = {
    category_id: category.id,
    description: this.product.description,
    images: await this.uploadImages(this.product.images),
    package_height: this.product.dimensions.height,
    package_length: this.product.dimensions.length,
    package_weight: this.product.weight.toString(),
    package_width: this.product.dimensions.width,
    product_attributes: await this.getAttributes(category.id),
    product_name: this.product.title,
    is_cod_open: false,
    skus: [
      {
        original_price: this.product.price.toString(),
        product_identifier_code: {
          identifier_code: this.product.ean13,
          identifier_code_type: IdentifierCodeType.EAN,
        }
      }
    ],
  } as T;

  if (brand) {
    data.brand_id = brand.id;
  }

  if (this.product.storefrontProductId) { 
    data.product_id = this.product.storefrontProductId;
  }

  return data;
}
```

It doesn't like me adding the product id though I get the following error:

```
Property 'product_id' does not exist on type 'CreateLocalProductRequestData | UpdateLocalProductRequestData'
```

How can I return the correct type with the correct data?

Comment: Please consider providing a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates your issue when others paste it as-is into their own IDEs. Right now I see a lot of unrelated errors about undeclared types and values, so I can't easily get to work on it. Ideally you'd remove anything that isn't directly needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling Typescript that `data` can be one of two types...either `CreateLocalProductRequestData` or `UpdateLocalProductRequestData`. That line of code is problematic because as far as Typescript is concerned, could be a `CreateLocalProductRequestData` which doesn't have the `product_id` property. You have to tell Typescript that is of that type. You can do this as follows:

```
(data as UpdateLocalProductRequestData).product_id = this.product.storefrontProductId;
```